# How to filter object with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter Object with multiple arrays based `onClick` event. I want to find array and find element in this concret array after filter it based which element is chosen by user.

```js
const dbData = {
    token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c',
    userData: {
        userEmail: 'test@gmail.com',
        phoneNumber: '123123123123',
        nickName: 'test-admin',
        todo: [
            {
                createdAt: new Date(),
                data: ['Go to barber', 'Go to gym', 'meet friends']
            },
            {
                createdAt: new Date(),
                data: ['got sleep', 'go to eat', 'go to travel']
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Comment: please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

here is explain mine problem solution if someone will have same problem

````
const deleteToDo = (id, value) => {
       const currTodoList = [...user.todoList];
       const elementIndex = currTodoList.findIndex(e => e.id === id);
       const deleteItem = currTodoList[elementIndex].data.filter(element => element !== value);
       currTodoList[elementIndex].data = deleteItem;
       setUserData({ todoList: currTodoList });
   };```
````